# Error calculation in the Backpropagation not working correctly

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

We are currently working on a project that involves Neural Networks. Our task consists of upscaling an 16x16 image all the way up to a picture with the resolution of 64x64.

The model used in the code example consists of only one Hidden-Layer with 5 Neurons in it. Furthermore the Hidden-Layer uses a ReLu function and the Output-Layer a simple linear one. The activations get saved and loaded , when they need to be accessed.

There is something wrong with the calculation of the Lost/Cost and therefore the weight's get updated the wrong way. The weight's keep getting bigger if their postive and more negative if they are negative.

We have seperated the Back-Propagation of the Hidden-Layer and the Output Layer, since they calculate the errors differently. There are also some Shape errors in the Back-Propagation for the first Hidden-Layer after the Output-Layer , which could indicate that the calculation is somewhat wrong. We used the website : https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backpropagation.html to get our errors calculated.

We are by no means expert's on the topic and would be happy to accept any help that we can get, so feel free to ask us any questions you like.

```
{def linearfunc(x): #The Linear Output function used for the Forward-Propagation
    return(x)

def linderiv(x):  #The Derivative of our Linear function used for the Back-Propagation
    return(1)

def backward(): #Back-Propagtion

    alpha = 0.001                                                       #Learning Rate

    Weights_Output = np.random.randn(5, 12288)   #Weights of the Output Layer / 5 is the number of neurons in the Hidden-Layer and 12228 the number of neurons in the Output Layer                                        
    Bias_Output = np.random.randn(12288,1)       #Bias of the Output Layer / 12288 is always derived from the features of the Output Image, which is 64*64*3 (3 For the RGB Values)

    Weights = np.random.randn(768,5)             #Weights of the only Hidden-Layer / The number 768 is derived from the number of input features of the images being 16*16*3
    Bias    = np.random.randn(5,1)               #Bias of the only Hidden-Layer

    #Start of the Back-Propagation for the Output-Layer
    DW_Output  = np.zeros((12288,5))                                    #Preparing the shapes of DW in the Output-Layer for the Back-Propagation
    DB_Output  = np.zeros((12288, 1))                                   #Preparing the shapes of DB in the Output-Layer for the Back-Propagation

    da_dz2    = linderiv(Z_Output)                                      #Applying the derivative of the Linear Function to our Z's in the Output-Layer / 1 Step                                                                 

    y         = np.load('DatasetY.npy')                                 #Loading our Output Features of our Dataset with the Y values            
    a         = np.load('Activations.npy')                              #Loading the Activations of the previous Layer before the Output-Layer / Our only Hidden-Layer

    Error_Output = (activations_Output-y) * da_dz2                      #Computing DZ(The Error) of our Output-Layer by using the formula Error = (Activations in the Output-Layer - Y-Values) multiplied with the derivative of the ReLu function applied to the Z's of the Output Layer
    DW_Output = np.dot(Error_Output , activations.T)                    #Computing DW of our Output-Layer by using the dot product of DZ_Output and our activations and then divide by the number of images in our Trainingset
    DB_Output = np.sum(Error_Output, axis = 1, keepdims = True) * (1/10000)#Computing DB of our Output-Layer by summing up all of the DZ's along axis 1 to get the right shape

    Weights_Output = Weights_Output - alpha * DW_Output.T               #The Weights of the Output Layer perform the Gradient Descent Step / The first time they update they all go way too high or too low
    Bias_Output = Bias_Output - alpha * DB_Output                       #The Bias of the Output Layer perform the Gradient Descent Step / The first time they update they all go way too high or too low

    #Start of the Back-Propagation for the Hidden-Layer

    dw  = np.zeros((5,768))                                                 #Preparing the shapes of dw in the only Hidden-Layer for the Back-Propagation
    db  = np.zeros((5, 1))                                                  #Preparing the shapes of dw in the only Hidden-Layer for the Back-Propagation

    a_2    = np.load('DatasetX.npy')                                        #Loading the activations of the Layer previous to out Hidden-Layer, which would be the Input Features

    da_dz   = z >= 0                                                        #Applying the derivative of the ReLu Function to our Z's in the Hidden-Layer / 1 Step               
    da_dz   = da_dz.astype(np.int)                                          #Turning all the TRUE values into 1 and all the FALSE values into 0 / 2 Step

    Error = Error_Output * np.dot(Weights_Output.T , da_dz)    #<< Gives a shape Error when Updating the Weight's #Computing dz(Error) in our Hidden-Layer by using the Weight's and the Error from the Output Layer and multiplying that with the derivative of the ReLu function applied to the  z's of the only Hidden-Layer
    dw = np.dot(Error, a_2.T) * (1/10000)                                   #Computing dw of our Hidden-Layer by using the dot product of dz and our activations and then divide by the number of images in our Trainingset
    db = (np.sum(Error, axis = 1, keepdims = True)) * (1/10000)             #Computing db of our Hidden-Layer by summing up all of the dz's along axis 1 to get the right shape

    Weights = Weights - alpha * dw.T                                        #The Weights of the Hidden-Layer perform the Gradient Descent Step / The first time they update they all go negative
    Bias = Bias - alpha * db                                                #The Bias of the Hidden-Layer perform the Gradient Descent Step / The first time they update they all go negative}
```